# Is there a WIndows 10 Home ARM

Tags: windows-10-preview, arm, license-key

I have downloaded and installed Windows 10 for ARM preview in a Parallels virtual machine. But it came in «Pro» version. Everything seems to work fine, but I can't personalize some settings because it is unlicensed.

My current Windows version license is «Home», and it comes from the free upgrade from Windows 7.

Does anybody know if ARM versions will have the «Home» version? If not, how long will I be able to use it without buying a Pro license?

Most of Microsoft online content about ARM is technical. I can't find anything about licenses.

Comment: Going by memory here... But I think entering Home key into Pro will downgrade it according to key.

Comment: It doesn’t matter since you cannot purchase a Windows 10 on ARM license separately.  You cannot use a Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional license to activate a Windows 10 on ARM installation